# Dreamweaver help needed with regular expression search and replace

Tags: regex, replace, dreamweaver

I've got a bit of an issue. I have lots of text document I need to copy into html to try and speed the procees up I've been looking into search and replace regular expressions to help me add bold tags to varies bits of text.

I have lots of text like this:

```
1. Centrum Multimineral Vitamin x 30 £3.19 was £4.79 (11p per tablet)
```

I'm trying to write a regular expression search and replace to look for all text between a number with a dot and space after it and the first price. I want the find and replace to do this:

```
<b>1. Centrum Multimineral Vitamin x 30 £3.19</b> was £4.79 (11p per tablet)
```

So far I've written this expression which kind of works:

search for:

```
([0-9]{1}[\.\s][\s\D]?[^<]*)(\£\d\.\d\d[^<])
```

replace with :

```
<b>$1$2</b>
```

Output :

```
<b>1. Centrum Multimineral Vitamin x 30 £3.19 was £4.79</b> (11p per tablet)
```

How do I alter this search so that it stops at the 1st £ sign and includes the price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this small modification:

```
([0-9]{1}[\.\s][\s\D]?[^<]*?)(\£\d\.\d\d[^<])
                           ^
```

I have added `?` which makes the asterisk `*` operator reluctant *(lazy)* so it reads the input string character by character instead of going all the way to the end, and then backtrack to try to find `\£\d\.\d\d[^<]`.

Comment: @Neb9 You are welcome, please don't forget to accept the answer if it fully solves your problem.

Comment: I dont suppose you know how to get this code working as a command?

Comment: @Neb9 Unfortunately I don't work with Dreamweaver, I just know about regular expressions :)

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway I think I've accepted the answer. I'm very new to this forum.

Comment: @Neb9 OK Thank you. You can check help forum or the faq for all information.